# Error while creating a clone role in wordpress

Tags: user-roles

I am trying to create a new member. The name of user role is Prime Members and those users should have same capabilities as customer.

I am using following code.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'cloneRole');

function cloneRole()
{
    global $wp_roles;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    $adm = $wp_roles->get_role('customer');
    //Adding a 'new_role' with all admin caps
    $wp_roles->add_role('prime_members', 'Prime Members', $adm->capabilities);
}
?>
```

When I click on update file button an error shows

> Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 644 of file C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwentyone\functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

> syntax error, unexpected token "<", expecting end of file

Comment: Welcome to wpse! My guess is you opened `<?php` and closed `?>` when you don't need to. `functions.php` already has `<?php` at the top and if you diden't mix html or closed that opening then you don't need to add it, try removing both `<?php` and `?>`

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, thanks, it works. Would you mind letting me know how I can create multiple roles? Do I need to paste same code again and again and assign new role, or I can create multipe roles in the same code?

Comment: The default customer capability is read, so the add role should be `$wp_roles->add_role('prime_members', 'Prime Members', ['read' => true])`. look at [add_role](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_role/) to understand better how to add capabilities, the basic is an array of capabilities that the key is the capability and the value is a boolean, `true` or `false`